# Always asking for password mapped Synology drive? How is it possible to save creds?

Tags: windows, webdav, nas, synology

1. I have a mapped drive on my Windows
2. For the first time it asks for the username and password which I've created on my NAS.
3. No problem, I log in, and can see my files on the server.
4. My problem is that if I open an Excel, or a Word file, then the Windows prompt keep asking for the username and the password,

I also tried the method of remembering them but failed, also tried to change the username for the same as the computer but it also failed.

I also tried adding a registry file which was offered on the Internet but that was also a failure.

My question is that how is it possible to solve this issue? I just want to ask for the username and password once, when I connect to the actual drive.

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Why don't you map a drive over SMB instead of WebDAV?